# Error al hacer Post en MongoDb con Mongoose

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy haciendo una api rest en node.js siguiendo un curso de gratuito de youtube y me pasa lo siguiente.
Resulta que al hacer la petición post yo envio una serie de valores para guardar en la base de datos pero lo que se guarda en ella son solamente el id generada por mongoose y la fecha de created y updated.

Schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const TracksScheme = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String
        },
        album: {
            type: String
        },
        cover: {
            type: String,
            validate: {
                validator: (req)=> {
                    return true;
                },
                message: "ERROR_URL",
            },
        },
        artist: {
            name: {
                type: String,
            },
            nickname: {
                type: String,
            },
            nationality: {
                type: String,
            }
        },
        duration: {
            start: {
                type: Number,
            },
            end: {
                type: Number,
            }
        },
        mediaId: {
            type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        }

    },{
        versionKey: false,
        timestamps: true,
    }
)
module.exports = mongoose.model("tracks", TracksScheme)
```

Cuerpo de la petición post:

```
{
    "data": {
        "name": "Nombre",
        "album": "Album",
        "cover": "http://tttt.com",
        "artist": {
            "name": "Nombre",
            "nickname": "nombrenick",
            "nationality": "VE"
        },
        "duration": {
            "start": 1,
            "end": 0
        },
        "mediaId": "662dds475786dasd9243652k3969"
    }
}
```

Funcion post en el controlador:

```
const createItem = async (req, res) => {
    const { body } = req;
    console.log(body);
    const data = await tracksModel.create(body);
    res.send({data});
}
```

y Finalmente lo que se guarda en la base de datos:

```
{
    "data": {
        "_id": "624d63a4946004d37bd0810a",
        "createdAt": "2022-04-06T09:55:48.626Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-04-06T09:55:48.626Z"
    }
}
```

He revisado repetidas veces el codigo y no le veo fallas, solo me queda pensar que pasa algo con MongoDB o Mongoose.

La version de mongoose es: "mongoose": "^6.2.10",
y la version de MongoDB es la 5.0.6

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado, en el controlador cambiar el:
const data = await tracksModel.create(body);
a:
const data = await tracksModel.create(body.data);

Y en el schema remplazar:
type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId
por:
type: String

Comment: Es mas practico y mas util que si `mediaId` es una relación a otra tabla, se almacene como `ObjectId` y no como `string`

Comment: @Pipe, querrás decir: *referencia a otro documento*. MongoDB no sabe nada de tablas ni de relaciones. ;) Y sí, lo suyo es cambiar el campo `mediaId` manualmente antes de general el documento con `create`. Hay muchas formas de hacerlo, pero si al OP le sirve su propia respuesta, ni modo.